# Graphics error on HP Thin Client T510

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, drivers

I started with Ubuntu 11.10 from usb. Upgraded to 12.4 LTS from inside the OS, then upgraded to 14.04 LTS. However, I received a graphics error and none of the fixes that I've found have worked.

I would like to go to the newest Ubuntu, but I am currently stumped. I've been reading forums for weeks and reinstalled the OS about 20 times. Now I'm trying to go to version 14.04 LTS or as high as the hardware will let me.

Hardware:

```
HP Thin Client T510
```

Mother board:

```
via vx900
```

Processor / Chipset:

```
CPU - VIA Eden X2 U4200 / 1 GHz
Number of Cores-Dual-Core
Chipset Type - VIA VX900
```

Memory

```
flash-1 gb
ram-2 GB SO-DIMM 204-pin(supports 4GB)1066 MHz 
hard drive- 320 gig
```

Networking

```
Data Link Protocol
Ethernet, Fast Ethernet, Gigabit Ethernet, IEEE 802.11a, IEEE 802.11b, IEEE 802.11g, IEEE 802.11n
Compliant Standards
IEEE 802.11a, IEEE 802.11b, IEEE 802.11g, IEEE 802.11n, IEEE 802.1x
Wireless LAN Supported- yes
Features
Wake on LAN (WoL), DHCP support, PXE support
DHCP support, PXE support, Wake on LAN (WoL)
```

Graphics Controller

```
integrated Graphics Processor VIA ChromotionHD 2.0
```

Video Interfaces

```
DVI, VGA
```

I added the 320GB HD and a Broadcom Crystal HD (Broadcom BCM70015 - which I couldn't ever get to work).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I just started throughing in random isos 12.04-16.04 and both versions of 16.04 64 and 32 work but there is only one resolution setting and the desktop is exploded zoomed in to an allmost unuseable point.

So it "works" now should I open another question for the resolution  problem ?

Comment: This appears to be the next question: [I only have one resolution 640x480 desktop looks zoomed in](https://askubuntu.com/q/765842/955434)