# I only have one resolution 640x480 desktop looks zoomed in

Tags: drivers, grub2, 16.04, hp, display-resolution

```
Hardware hp thin client T510-  
Mother board via vx900  
CPU - VIA Eden X2 U4200 / 1 GHz Dual-Core  
Chipset Type - VIA VX900
Memory - flash - 1 GB, RAM - 2 GB SO-DIMM 204-pin(supports 4GB)1066 MHz 
Hard drive - 320 GB
```

Networking

```
Data Link Protocol
Ethernet, Fast Ethernet, Gigabit Ethernet, IEEE 802.11a, IEEE 802.11b, IEEE 802.11g, IEEE 802.11n
Compliant Standards
IEEE 802.11a, IEEE 802.11b, IEEE 802.11g, IEEE 802.11n, IEEE 802.1x
Wireless LAN Supported- yes
```

Features
    Wake on LAN (WoL), DHCP support, PXE support
    DHCP support, PXE support, Wake on LAN (WoL)

Graphics Controller

```
integrated Graphics Processor VIA ChromotionHD 2.0
```

Video Interfaces

```
DVI, VGA
```

I added the 320 GB hd and a braodcom crystal HD broadcom bcm70015 (which I couldn't ever get to work)

```
$ lspci |grep VGA
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX900 Graphics [Chrome9HD]                                                                                                                                                             xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       73.00*
```

Answer (score 6):

fixed by using

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

locate line `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`

delete the `#` and replace `640x480` with `1024x480`

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/grub.d/00_header
```

find line `gfxmode=(grub_GFXMODE)` and under that add

```
set gfx payload=keep
```

Ran `sudo update-grub`

then ran `xdiagnose` from dash checked all debug options

Boomshackalack. Usable desktop.

Comment: It worked wonderfully! For the record, my graphic card is an integrated VIA chipset CN986/VN896/P4M900 [Chrome 9 HC]

Comment: For me line is like **set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}** , so **set gfx payload=keep** will come under this line ?